# XSS vulnerability: <wslite>

Tags: php, security, xss

A scurity report for my website show this vulnerability:

```
Relflected XSS:  
Request: GET http://example.com/page.php?q=< wslite > HTTP/1.1
```

what is the meaning of this error, what is the meaning of `<wslite>`? and how can I solve this problem?

thanks

Comment: You should be seeing `<wslite>` somewhere in your HTML code when you call that URL. The function that puts it there is the culprit, you'll need to fix it... Best show the appropriate code here.

Comment: [Cross Site Scripting(XSS) on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)

Answer (score 0):

It means there is a GET vulnerability within the `?q` section of your site. They can implant code there. Try visiting your site with `?q=<u>XSS</u>`, and it should bring up the word XSS (underlined) somewhere within the page. These can be very dangerous. So ensure you sort it out. Update whatever CMS you are using, or use `htmlentities()` in PHP to ensure the user cannot insert HTML.